# Using Gateway to consume Spring Boot application from Spring Integration application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am just starting with Spring Integration with Spring Boot 2.

I am working on a application which uses Spring Integration's HTTP outbound gateway to consume a Spring boot Service.

I am consuming the spring boot service from Spring Integration application using Gateway.

When I call the Gateway method which in turn will use the outbound gateway to call the spring boot service, the request does not seem to be completed. It is just going on when I make the HTTP GET request via the browser.

The request is also not received by the Spring Boot service.

I am not able to identify what is wrong in my Integration application when using gateway to consume a Spring Boot 2 service.

I have shared my Spring Boot 2 Application and also the Integration application which I am using to consume it in the below github folder. it contains 2 folders, one for the spring Integration application and the other for the spring boot application.
https://github.com/gsamartian/spring-int-demos

I have exposed a REST interface for the Integration application using RestController.

I access the boot application from integration application via the url, http://localhost:8763/callExternalServiceViaGateway

I am able to access the spring boot application directly from its port.

If anyone can help me identify the cause it would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that the gateway method is without any args:

```
@Gateway(requestChannel = "get.request.channel", replyChannel = "reply.channel")
String getCustomMessage();
```

In this case the gateway works as *receiving*. No any requests is send because nothing to wrap to the `payload`. See more info on the matter in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods).

Right now I see several bugs with the `payloadExpression` and no arg, so I suggest you to add some `String payload` arg to the `getCustomMessage()` gateway method and perform it with an empty string.

Will take a look into the bugs and will fix them soon.

Thank you for a good sample how to catch and reproduce!

https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4448

https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4449